# How to read and get data from excel .xlsx

Tags: c#, database, excel

I have excel file with 2 tables. I need to read this tables and get all the values from this tables. But all for what I have is:

```
OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\MigrateExelSql\Include\TestDb.xlsx; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");

OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", cnn);
cnn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);
```

And I don't uderstand what I need to write for get the all values from Username and Email tables. Here is the .xlsx table [TestDb](http://www.screencast.com/t/nCaeW6YZo) Please can somebody help me, because I'm googling the second day and I have no idea for what I must to do.

And when I try to get values by this method it return me an error:

```
        var fileName = string.Format("{0}\\Include\\TestDb.xlsx", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", fileName);

        var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connectionString);
        var ds = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(ds, "Username");

        var data = ds.Tables["Username"].AsEnumerable();
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

One more Edit:

```
string con =
            @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\MigrateExelSql\Include\TestDb.xlsx; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(con))
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection); 
            using(OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                 while(dr.Read())
                 {
                     var row1Col0 = dr[0];
                     Console.WriteLine(row1Col0);
                 }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

This will read only first column, but when I try to read dr[1] it will return error: Index was outside bound of the array.

Comment: Well, the first think you should do is to tell us what error you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xlsx file contains only one sheet and in that sheet there is only one column. 
A sheet is treated by the OleDb driver like a datatable and each column in a sheet is considered a datacolumn.

You can't read anything apart one table `(Sheet1$)` and one column `(dr[0])`.
If you try to read `dr[1]` then you are referencing the second column and that column doesn't exist in `Sheet1`.

Just to test, try to add some values in the second column of the Excel file.
Now you can reference `dr[1]`.

Comment: You're right, I have an error, because I forget to add the second column. Thank you a lot

Comment: The file supplied has only one column and the value in that column is not an email. But suppose that in the first column of the xlsx file you write usernames and in the second column the email addresses. In this case you can read the email column using the syntax above `dr[1]`, but you need to have two columns in the Excel file at the Sheet1